# Need help in Looping through 2 Nested Arrays in Javascript/AngularJS and do Comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to compare two arrays and push elements to one array , if none of the objects in that array match the second array.

Please find my JSON's below:

Array 1:

```
"[{
"carrierName":"A",
"id":7,
"active":true
"subList":[{
"active":false,
"carrierServiceId":"19",
"locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 4",
"locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
"locationStateCode":"NJ",
"locationZipcode":"56324",
"name":"A 4"}
,
{
"active":true,
"carrierServiceId":"20",
"locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 1",
"locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
"locationStateCode":"NJ",
"locationZipcode":"56324",
"name":"A 1"
},
{
"active":true,
"carrierServiceId":"21",
"locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 2",
"locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
"locationStateCode":"NJ",
"locationZipcode":"56324",
"name":"A 2"},
{
"active":true,
"carrierServiceId":"22",
"id":1001,
"locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 3",
"locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
"locationStateCode":"NJ",
"locationZipcode":"56324",
"name":"A 3"
}
]
}
]"
```

Array 2:

```
"[{"subList":[
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"20",
      "id":0,
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 1",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
      "name":"A 1",
   },
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"21",
      "id":0,
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 2",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
      "name":"A 2",
   },
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"22",
      "id":0,
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 3",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
      "name":"A 3",
   },
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"19",
      "id":0,
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"ABC 4",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"1111",
      "name":"A 4",
   }
],
"active":false,
"id":7,
"name":"A",
},
{
"subList":[
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"7",
      "id":0,
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"DEF 1",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"2222",
      "name":"B 1",
   },
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"8",
      "id":0,
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"DEF 2",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"2222",
      "name":"B 2",
   },
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"9",
      "id":0,
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"DEF 3",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"2222",
      "name":"B 3",
   }
],
"active":false,
"id":8,
"name":"B",
},
{
"subList":[
   {
      "active":true,
      "code":"10",
      "locationPrimaryContactName":"GHI 1",
      "locationPrimaryContactNumber":"3333",
      "name":"C 1",
   }
],
"active":false,
"id":9,
"name":"C",
},
{
"subList":[

],
"active":false,
"id":10,
"name":"D",
}
]"
```

Here if you see, the common fields are id, sublist.carrierServiceId in Array 1 & subList.code in Array 2.
My requirement is that I need to loop through Array 1 and Array 2 and add the elements from Array 2 to Array 1, if it does not exist it Array 1. When adding, need to check the "subList" array as well for any particular "id" in Array 2 and if those exist in Array 1, they too should not be added.

Request any expert help on this. Please let me know if the query needs more clarity.

Comment: please add the wanted result and the code you tried.

Comment: for example, what should happen with `code = 7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correct, the you need to get all elements of array 2 into array 1 at the right place.

This works with a reference to the given objects and creates a new one if necessary.

```js
var array1 = [{ carrierName: "A", id: 7, active: true, subList: [{ active: false, carrierServiceId: "19", locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 4", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", locationStateCode: "NJ", locationZipcode: "56324", name: "A 4" }, { active: true, carrierServiceId: "20", locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 1", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", locationStateCode: "NJ", locationZipcode: "56324", name: "A 1" }, { active: true, carrierServiceId: "21", locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 2", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", locationStateCode: "NJ", locationZipcode: "56324", name: "A 2" }, { active: true, carrierServiceId: "22", id: 1001, locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 3", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", locationStateCode: "NJ", locationZipcode: "56324", name: "A 3" }] }],
    array2 = [{ subList: [{ active: true, code: "20", id: 0, locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 1", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", name: "A 1", }, { active: true, code: "21", id: 0, locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 2", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", name: "A 2", }, { active: true, code: "22", id: 0, locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 3", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", name: "A 3", }, { active: true, code: "19", id: 0, locationPrimaryContactName: "ABC 4", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "1111", name: "A 4", }], active: false, id: 7, name: "A", }, { subList: [{ active: true, code: "7", id: 0, locationPrimaryContactName: "DEF 1", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "2222", name: "B 1", }, { active: true, code: "8", id: 0, locationPrimaryContactName: "DEF 2", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "2222", name: "B 2", }, { active: true, code: "9", id: 0, locationPrimaryContactName: "DEF 3", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "2222", name: "B 3", }], active: false, id: 8, name: "B", }, { subList: [{ active: true, code: "10", locationPrimaryContactName: "GHI 1", locationPrimaryContactNumber: "3333", name: "C 1", }], active: false, id: 9, name: "C", }, { subList: [], active: false, id: 10, name: "D" }],
    reference = {};

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!reference[a.id]) {
        reference[a.id] = { data: a, children: {} };
    }
    a.subList.forEach(function (b) {
        reference[a.id].children[b.carrierServiceId] = b;
    });
});

array2.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!reference[a.id]) {
        reference[a.id] = { data: { carrierName: a.name, id: a.id, active: a.active, subList: [] }, children: {} };
        array1.push(reference[a.id].data);
    }
    a.subList.forEach(function (b) {
        if (!reference[a.id].children[b.code]) {
            reference[a.id].children[b.code] = {
                active: b.active,
                carrierServiceId: b.code,
                locationPrimaryContactName: b.locationPrimaryContactName,
                locationPrimaryContactNumber: b.locationPrimaryContactNumber,
                // locationStateCode: b.locationPrimaryContactNumber,
                // locationZipcode: b.locationZipcode,
                name: b.name
            };
            reference[a.id].data.subList.push(reference[a.id].children[b.code]);
        }
    });
});

console.log(array1);
```